# DB2 creating year and Quarter and week from timestamp

Tags: db2

I separated the time stamp to year and quarter and week using this query

select EVENTTIMESTAMP, Year (EVENTTIMESTAMP), QUARTER (EVENTTIMESTAMP),  Week (EVENTTIMESTAMP) from KAP.COGNOS

there only two things i was trying to enhance in it 
1- the weeks returns a number between 1-54, I want it to be return 13 or 14 weeks as weeks of Quarters.

2- to add word before the number of Quarter 'Quarter' and then it's number, and so to the weeks to show word 'Week' then the number

Many Thanks!!

Comment: It'd possibly be better to edit one of your existing questions to add details about your problem, since many of them all seem to point to the same problem. A comprehensive question that includes details of your database along with a clear description of your actual problem could yield a comprehensive answer. In your case, you seem to have your own definition of "week" that doesn't match accepted business accounting meanings. As such, you'll possibly need to create your own calendar file and assign your "weeks" as you need. Extract weeks from it based on your dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DB2 separate number of weeks per quarter from timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706814/db2-separate-number-of-weeks-per-quarter-from-timestamp)