# DB2 separate number of weeks per quarter from timestamp

Tags: db2

I'm trying to separate weeks from timestamp per quarter so it should be between 1-13 week per quarter so I used function `week()` but it takes between 1-52 week as whole year so I made it to be divided by function of quarter like below

```
select Week (EVENTTIMESTAMP) / QUARTER (EVENTTIMESTAMP) from KAP
```

The thing here that results aren't accurate; for example it shows:

```
time stamp 2014-07-06 12:13:03.018 

week number 9
```

which isn't correct because July is first month in Q3 and it's in the 6 days so it should be 1 week from Q3 not 9.

Any suggestion where it go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You want something like `WEEK modulo 13` to get week number within a quarter.  You will have to tinker with 'modulo 13 yields 0..12' by adding or subtracting one at appropriate points.

Some minimal Google searching using 'ibm db2 sql modulo' yields DB2 [MOD](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_mod.dita?lang=en) function:

> The MOD function divides the first argument by the second argument and returns the remainder.

Hence `MOD(WEEK(...), 13)`, except you probably need `MOD(WEEK(...)-1, 13) + 1`, as intimated already.

You may need to watch for what the [WEEK()](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_week.dita?lang=en) function does at year ends:

> The WEEK function returns an integer in the range of 1 to 54 that represents the week of the year. The week starts with Sunday, and January 1 is always in the first week.

I'm curious about how they can come up with week 54.  I suppose it requires 1st January to be a Saturday (so 2nd January is the start of week 2) of a leap year, as in 2000 and 2028.  Note that week 53 and (occasionally) week 54 will show up as weeks 1 and 2 of Q5 unless you do something.  Also, Saturday 2000-03-25 would be the end of Q1 and Sunday 2000-03-26 would be the start of Q2 under the regime imposed by the `WEEK()` function and a simple `MOD(WEEK(...), 13)` calculation.  You're likely to have to tune this to meet your real requirements.

There's also the [WEEK_ISO()](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_weekiso.dita?lang=en) function:

> The WEEK_ISO function returns an integer in the range of 1 to 53 that represents the week of the year. The week starts with Monday and includes seven days. Week 1 is the first week of the year that contains a Thursday, which is equivalent to the first week that contains January 4.

Note that under the ISO scheme, the 3rd of January can be in week 52 or 53 of the previous year, and the 29th of December can be in week 1 of the next year.  Curiously, there doesn't seem to be a YEAR_ISO() function to resolve such ambiguities.

Comment: what is week modulo 13? which function would be helpful at that i was trying the following :

  SELECT datediff (week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, EVENTTIMESTAMP), 0), EVENTTIMESTAMP) +1 AS WeekNoMonth,DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, EVENTTIMESTAMP), 0), EVENTTIMESTAMP) +1 AS WeekNoQuarter

to get both weeks no in quarter and months but found out that date diff not supported on DB2 any suggestions 

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: I'm not sure. However, it might be a function such as `MOD(WEEK(...), 13)`, possibly with adjustments, or it might be an operator (which tends to be `%`, as in `WEEK(...) % 13`). The function name might be `MOD` or something else (`MODULO`, ...).  You'll have to hit the manuals for the details.  But the basic point is that the week within quarter is not produced by division but by remainder. I assume you have link to the relevant DB2 manuals. I note that you don't stipulate which version of DB2 you are using, nor the platform on which you are using it. It may not matter much.

Comment: A Google search 'ibm db2 sql modulo' yields DB2 [MOD](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_mod.dita?lang=en) function.  Hence `MOD(WEEK(...), 13)`, except you probably need `MOD(WEEK(...)-1, 13) + 1`, as intimated already.

Answer (score 0):

In a data warehouse, the proper solution to this is to create a time dimension that contains static mappings for days/weeks/months/quarters/years.  This provides the ability to define these based on your business' fiscal calendar (if it is not following on the calendar year).

See: http://www.kimballgroup.com/1997/07/10/its-time-for-time/ for more information.